# ionic sidemenu on mobile browser not working smoothly

Tags: mobile-website, frame-rate, ionic-framework

I am developing mobile web app using ionic sidemenu, but it is not as smooth as it should be. When I open sidemenu using slide left/right, I am getting less than 30 FPS as shown in figure.


 [image: Timeline of ionic sidemenu toggle]


How can I improve the performance? 
Reaching 60 FPS would be great!

Comment: Can you make a codepen or plunkr example that I can use to test and reproduce?

Comment: are you using a lot of shadows and gradients as these produce slow performance at times. ANother small hack will be to use an ng-if on the content of the side menu so they only show up when the side menu has opened and are ejected from dom when its not there. I used this on a modal and it improved performance so maybe will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

AppGyver's [Steroids tooling](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids) also provides you with access to Crosswalk on Android. You can [run it in your Ionic project](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/cli/usage-with-cordova/) directly without modifying any files.

Also, [Supersonic's](http://www.appgyver.com/supersonic) sidemenu/drawer is fully native, so if you're up for migrating, it'll run way faster. :)

(Disclaimer: I'm a programmer for AppGyver.)

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) instead of the [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) as the webview for the app.

While both share the same end goal, they are different:

- **Cordova**, from the Apache Foundation, uses the regular (pre-lollipop) Android webview, which is based on Android's stock browser since its inception.
- The **Crosswalk Project**, created on the Intel Open Source Technology Center, is different. It wraps your app with Chromium, the open-source base code that gave birth to Google Chrome, which brings numerous performance enhancements: css3 transitions, animations, 3d transformations, html5 support, remote debugging and much better javascript support and performance.

At the time of writing, the Ionic team is already working on a beta version (1.3.0-beta1) that uses Crosswalk instead of Cordova. Not really stable just yet, but a huge promise.

In any case, you can use Crosswalk today, by manually copying your Ionic project's 'www' 
folder content to the project folder inside Crosswalk folder and run it. You'll need to setup some manifest files previously, so read the docs.

In any case, it's not hard at all to try, and I'll recommend it everyday for all projects pre-Lollipop. If you're targeting Lollipop/Android 5 versions, you don't need it, because the default Webview in these versions is already Chrome-based.

Hope it helps.