# Cordova / Phonegap App is slow in some Android devices

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I used ionic framework for building my android app. I tried it in Sony Xperia T(Jellybean 4.3)it works smooth.

But in MOTO G (Kitkat 4.4.4) and Xperia Z(Jellybean 4.3)is very slow. Is it a problem with ionic framework / Cordova?

Comment: What exactly isn't smooth? i have exact same problem.transition from one page to another and scrolling the contents are very slow.

Comment: Yes i have noticed that performance is inconsistent on android unlike IOS where it is butter smooth. One way to solve this is to use ng-if on the pages being transitioned to and then animate the content in. I used this for a model and it was smooth. Try it not a complete solution but a step 4ward

Answer (score 0):

Having experienced the same on my apps, my advice is to try to replace Cordova by the [Crosswalk Project](https://crosswalk-project.org/). Its very easy to build the app manually, and the Ionic team is working to replace it inside their own app builder (Ionic version 1.3.0-beta1).

Here's a slightly more detailed explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27888495/1368810

Hope it helps.

Comment: An note to anyone who has found this post. The crosswalk project is not being maintained anymore: https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html